# Communicating with another component without @Output()

Tags: angular, typescript

As an alternative implementation to an output data flow I have created the workflow I mention below, my question is what is this approach called as I want to get more information on this and if there are any drawbacks to this:

See implementation here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eg9bm4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Workflow:

- Pass an interface with a function property that updates an instance variable to a child input property of another component

eg:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-component-a",
  template: `
    <app-component-b [inputValue]="testConfig"></app-component-b> {{ value }}
  `
})
export class AppComponentA {
  value = 0;

  testConfig: testConfig = {
    testFunction: (obj: testReturnObject) => {
      this.value = obj.outputVariable;
    }
  };
}
```

- On a button press pass a value into the input variable function

eg:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-component-b",
  template: '<button (click)="doSomething()">button</button>'
})
export class AppComponentB {
  @Input() inputValue: testConfig;

  doSomething() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    this.inputValue.testFunction({ outputVariable: randomNumber });
  }
}
```

Comment: That would probably cause bugs and miss change detection (I could be wrong though, Angular change detection is complicated). In any case, if you want to communicate 2 unrelated components I suggest injecting a service

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is a solution for a reusable component so unfortunately a service wouldn't help my particular use case. I got the inspiration from a popular commercial library so I am hoping this won't be a buggy solution but you never know -  hence I am trying to find more info.

Comment: Why you think service wouldn't help you, because you could use observable to communicate between components

Comment: @JonathanLopez because I might as well just emit the value from the reusable component

Comment: why you suggesting `callback` method instead of `@Output` decorator.